# comparing effect sizes of a multi-level predictor

Tags: effect-size

Hopefully this is a simple question. I am seeking a way to compare the effect size of a factor with multiple levels under two different conditions. For example, consider a situation where the per acre yield of 5 different cultivars (varieties) of corn are significantly different. However, I expect the magnitude of these differences to be reduced under drought conditions. I set up an experiment (with a fully balanced design and well replicated) where I include all 5 varieties and simulate drought or non-drought conditions. I can perform an ANOVA and find that variety, drought and their interaction are all highly significant predictors of yield. But, I would like to test whether the magnitude of the variation in yield among cultivars is different under drought or non-drought conditions. I can compare the variance among cultivars under the two treatments and see that it is substantially lower under drought, but I am not sure the best way to test this statistically. Any help would be greatly appreciated.